# ref.current is always undefined when using ref from forwardRef

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "left"
};

const Wrapper = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  return <App ref={ref} />;
};

const App = React.forwardRef(
  ({ placeHolder, onNameSelected, error, onSuggestion }, ref) => {
    ref.current.setAttribute("he-de-data", "");

    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <h4>Username</h4>
        <input ref={ref} />
      </div>
    );
  }
);

render(<Wrapper />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-16-v0kn4) that can help you out:

I have the following code, but ref.current is undefined. I need to use the ref from `forwardRef` and use that ref to add some attribute to the DOM. However, the `ref.current` is always **undefined**. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: You can use `data-xxx` to add attribute to the DOM Instead of `ref`. `<input data-he-de-data={...}/>`

Comment: I want to avoid doing that, because it's a component that's going to be part of a library for other projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are using ref and forwardRef incorrectly.

forwardRef is used because functional components cant be instantiated so if you assign a ref to any functional component you created it will be null. what forwardRef does is it forwards the ref to the component it is wrapping and then you can assign it to any html element inside your component, there by giving you access to the DOM from the **PARENT** .

What you want to do is to set the attribute from within the component itself and not from the parent. so forward ref is not required

```
 const Comp =({ placeHolder, onNameSelected, error, onSuggestion }) => {
       const inputRef = useRef(null);
       useEffect(()=>{
          if(inputRef.current!==null)
          inputRef.current.setAttribute("he-de-data", "");
        },[]);

    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <h4>Username</h4>
        <input ref={inputRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-16-v0kn4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: What if you need to do it outside of a component? Let's say input is actually AutoComplete a component from another library?

Comment: then you need to use forward ref

Comment: what if all parent components are functional components?

Comment: doesnt matter what the parent is. forward ref is used for the child if its a functional component as it cant instantiate like class components.

Answer (score 0):

ref.current will be undefined on the first render. Its needs to create all the dom nodes + children before it can assign the ref. You can guard against it with something like

```
let inner = null;
if (ref.current !== undefined) {
    // do whatever you want with the ref here
}
```

Also you may want to check you logic when assigning inner. setAttribute doesnt return anything

Comment: It never runs when I use the if statement.

Comment: Yes because your wrapper never re-renders. You will need to get the wrapper to update if you want to do that.